# How to execute a MATLAB script in cygwin?

Tags: windows, matlab, cygwin

As the title of the question says, I would like to call a matlab script from the cygwin shell in windows 7. Is there a way to do so? I could not find anything about it either here or anywhere else online.

Edit: I do not whish to call a unix command from within matlab, but rather the other way around. E.g. I want to do something like

```
$ matlab MatScript.m
```

from the cygwin shell.

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/304859

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm looking for. 

That thread explains how to use cygwin commands from within a matlab script, while I need the other way around. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Have you seen the [MATLAB command-line documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html)? I believe the `-r` switch is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The command `matlab -r MathScript.m` is probably what you are looking for.
And if it doesn't work, leave the file extension (".m") out.